# leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40810e90 that was originally added here

Tags: android, calendar

```
private static void addToCalendar(ActivityAppointment ctx, final String title, final long dtstart, final long dtend) {
    final ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor ;
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    else
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        final String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
            calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
            calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(calNames, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("calendar_id", calIds[which]);
                cv.put("title", title);
                cv.put("dtstart", dtstart );
                cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                cv.put("dtend", dtend);

                Uri newEvent ;
                if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
                else
                    newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);

                if (newEvent != null) {
                    long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put( "event_id", id );
                    values.put( "method", 1 );
                    values.put( "minutes", 15 ); // 15 minutes
                    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                        cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://com.android.calendar/reminders" ), values );
                    else
                        cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://calendar/reminders" ), values );

                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        builder.create().show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

and this method i called in some other function

```
    public void SaveData()
  { 
                .......
              addToCalendar(this, edSubject.getText().toString(), startMillis, endMillis);
}
```

my logcat error is:

```
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166): Activity com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.activities.ActivityAppointment has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40810e90 that was originally added here
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.activities.ActivityAppointment has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40810e90 that was originally added here
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:291)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:249)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:532)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:269)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.activities.ActivityAppointment.SaveData(ActivityAppointment.java:381)
01-16 17:17:56.740: E/WindowManager(4166):  at com.sree.weekdayview.calendar.activities.ActivityAppointment$3.onClick(ActivityAppointment.java:123)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because of the dialog you're showing. Dialogs are tightly bound to the life cycle of their hosts (activities), which means that generally you should not attempt to create and/or show a dialog outside of the dedicated platform methods. In your case the activity problably gets destroyed (e.g. because of an orientation change) while the dialog is displaying, hence the exception.

There are two approaches to bind the life cycle of dialog up to that of its host:

1. Up until API level 13, the dedicated platform methods were `onCreateDialog()` (and `showDialog()` / `dismissDialog()`). They are available within an activity and should be overridden to create/show/dismiss dialogs on an id basis.
2. Starting API level 13 the above methods are deprecated in favour of `DialogFragment`, which is a fragment wrapper around a dialog whose life cycle is managed by the `FragmentManager`.

Your third option, which I would recommend, is to use the `DialogFragment` approach in combination with the support library. That's basically option two but using backported functionality that enables the modern logic to work on devices running Android 1.6 and up.

For implementation details, refer to the [Dialogs topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) on the Android dev site. An example using the deprecated approach can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDialogs/article.html).